# How to fetch the no. of Users dynamically?

Tags: themes

i am developing a review website of chome plugins..

[Here](http://tech-url.com/wordpress/?review=turn-off-the-lights)
you can see the sample post ..

I want the no. of users to be fetched on the real time.
In this case from this [web store page.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/turn%20off%20the%20lights?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

For this I have also made a php function which i have put on 
demo at tech-url.com

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: <?php


$url=$_POST['url'];
//URL of your extension
//$url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dropbox/ioekoebejdcmnlefjiknokhhafglcjdl";

//Get the nb of users
$file_string = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('#>([0-9,+]*) users</#i', $file_string, $users);
$nbusers = str_replace(",", "",$users[1]);
echo $nbusers; //Display the number of users


?>

Comment: for **paste here the code** I mean: **edit the answer and paste the code there** However, as I guessed, for me this is off-topic

Comment: For this you can use WordPress heartbeat api http://pippinsplugins.com/using-the-wordpress-heartbeat-api/